# Using MS Access to create tables using SQL statements?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I go to Create tab and hit Query Design and then SQL view and enter the following. But it doesn't run. I've tried googling and I follow those rules and I still get errors. I've change the statement every way I know and it still doesn't run. What am I doing wrong?
Note: Last Name has to be VARCHAR and Commission and Rate both have to be NUMBER.

I redid it with some of the suggests and changed it to this.

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_REP
(REP_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15),
FIRST_NAME CHAR(15),
STREET CHAR(15),
CITY CHAR(15),
STATE CHAR(2),
POSTAL_CODE CHAR(5),
COMMISSION NUMBER(7,2),
RATE NUMBER(3,2) );
```

> Syntax error in CREATE TABLE STATEMENT

Comment: Which errors are you getting exactly? Edit your question with that please.

Comment: remove the space in your table name. Change it to Sales_Rep

Comment: POSTAL_CODE needs a data type.

Comment: Surround your table name in brackets:  `[SALES REP]`. Table names are allowed to have spaces, but only if encased in brackets.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you targetting? An Access back-end, MySql, or MSSQL? You can't possibly be working in all 3.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, if you want DDL to specify *Scale* and *Precision* for a numeric field, use `DECIMAL` as the field type.

```sql
CREATE TABLE SALES_REP
(REP_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15),
FIRST_NAME CHAR(15),
STREET CHAR(15),
CITY CHAR(15),
STATE CHAR(2),
POSTAL_CODE CHAR(5),
COMMISSION DECIMAL(7,2),
[RATE] DECIMAL(3,2));
```

Notice I bracketed the field name `[RATE]` so the db engine won't confuse it with the VBA `Rate()` function.

**Beware** in order for `DECIMAL` to be supported you must execute the statement from ADO/OleDb.  I executed it with`CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`, which is an ADO method, like this ...

```vb
Dim strDdl As String
strDdl = "CREATE TABLE SALES_REP" & vbCrLf & _
    "(REP_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY," & vbCrLf & _
    "LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15)," & vbCrLf & _
    "FIRST_NAME CHAR(15)," & vbCrLf & _
    "STREET CHAR(15)," & vbCrLf & _
    "CITY CHAR(15)," & vbCrLf & _
    "STATE CHAR(2)," & vbCrLf & _
    "POSTAL_CODE CHAR(5)," & vbCrLf & _
    "COMMISSION DECIMAL(7,2)," & vbCrLf & _
    "[RATE] DECIMAL(3,2));"
Debug.Print strDdl
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
```

Executing the same statement from DAO (`CurrentDb.Execute strDdl` or from the query designer) will trigger a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Use double instead of number:

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_REP
(REP_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15),
FIRST_NAME CHAR(15),
STREET CHAR(15),
CITY CHAR(15),
STATE CHAR(2),
POSTAL_CODE VARCHAR(5),
COMMISSION DOUBLE,
RATE DOUBLE );
```

Comment: Why will Number not work? It's working due to the change to DOUBLE, but the book wants it listed as NUMBER?

Comment: It isn't a valid Ms access datatype